# Swift step through dictionary

Tags: swift, swift3

I was wondering if there's a way to step through a dictionary in Swift. I know I can iterate through, but I was hoping to step one by one through a dictionary of items as the user taps a "next" button.

I was thinking I could initially iterate through the dictionary and store the keys in an array, then step through the keys and retrieve each item as needed, since the array can be indexed. This seems a little inelegant, though. Any thoughts?

My current approach:

```
var iterator = 0
var keys = [String]()

func loadKeys() {
    for (key, value) in items {
        keys.append(key)
    }
}

func step() {
    iterator += 1
    let currentKey = keys[iterator]
    let currentItem = items[currentKey]
}
```

I figure it would work just fine, just not sure it's the best practice.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: On the button click could you not just get the next index of the dictionary and couldn't it as it goes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dictionary also provides you with an iterator, so you can step through it using that:

```
var iterator = items.makeIterator()

func step() {
  if let v = iterator.next() {
     let currentKey = v.key
     let currentValue = v.value
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary is an indexed collection, so you can use a dictionary's index to step through the keys and values:

```
var i = items.startIndex

func step() {
    guard i != items.endIndex else {
        // at the end of the dictionary
        return
    }

    let (currentKey, currentValue) = items[i]
    i = items.index(after: i)
}
```